# issues in fixing nested promises that are depended with each other

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I am new to JS and I am having a hard time refactoring my code, i know this is not the right way to write nested promised. and i want to refactor it correctly but i am having errors on every attempt. i am getting confused because some calls are depended on the previous one so i am not sure how to structure it properly

this is my original nested code:

```
this.props.actionHandler.createDivisionList(this.state.divisionQnAListName).then(listData => {
  console.log(listData, "in list creation");
  //createListFields 
  this.props.actionHandler.createListFields(listData.data.Title).then(res=>{
    //addFieldsToView (
    console.log(res, "after list field creation");
    this.props.actionHandler.addFieldsToView(listData.data.Title).then(r => {
      this.props.actionHandler.createSharePointGroup(this.state.divisionName).then(groupInfo => {
        console.log(groupInfo, "in group creation");
        //add users to group 
        this.props.actionHandler.addUsersToSPGroup(groupInfo.data.Title,userwithIds).then(afterAdd => {
          //break list permission
          this.props.actionHandler.breakListPermission(this.state.divisionQnAListName).then(afterBreak => {
            //addGroup to list
            this.props.actionHandler.addGroupToList(this.state.divisionQnAListName,faqAdminGroup[0].Id,fullControlPermission).then(admin => {
              this.props.actionHandler.addGroupToList(this.state.divisionQnAListName,groupInfo.data.Id,contributePermission).then(last => {

                this.props.actionHandler.saveMasterItemtoSPList(this.props.masterListName,formData).then(res => {
                  //if success pass success else pass fail to the container
                  console.log(res, "after saving!");
                  //this.props.onSubmission(res);
                });
              });
            });
          });
        });  
      });
    });
  });
});
```

and this is my attempt, i tried assigning the response to a variable to be passed to the other calls that needs that data. but i get undefined.

```
let groupData;

this.props.actionHandler.createDivisionList(this.state.divisionQnAListName)
.then(lst => {
  console.log(lst, "in list creation"); 
  return this.props.actionHandler.createListFields(lst.data.Title)
  .then(()=> this.props.actionHandler.addFieldsToView(lst.data.Title));          
})
.then(() => {
  return this.props.actionHandler.createSharePointGroup(this.state.divisionName)
  .then(grp =>  {
    console.log(grp, "group created");
    groupData = grp;
    return this.props.actionHandler.addUsersToSPGroup(grp.data.Title,userwithIds)
  })
  .then(() =>  this.props.actionHandler.breakListPermission(this.state.divisionQnAListName))
  .then(groupData=> {
    return Promise.all([
      this.props.actionHandler.addGroupToList(this.state.divisionQnAListName,faqAdminGroup[0].Id,fullControlPermission),
      this.props.actionHandler.addGroupToList(this.state.divisionQnAListName,groupData.data.Id,contributePermission)
    ])
    .then(() => this.props.actionHandler.saveMasterItemtoSPList(this.props.masterListName,formData)).then(res => {
      console.log(res, "after saving!");
      return this.props.onSubmission(res);
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: `formData` from where is this coming, or is it just a typo for `groupData`?

Comment: `actionHandler.breakListPermission`, what will be response for it, is it `groupData `?

Comment: @RaghavGarg, hi thats just my form data that i need to save after all the previous calls has been successful. that's outside the calls

Comment: @Ragh breakList permission is not dependent anything. i just need to break the list permission of a sharepoint list. but it should run before i call addGroupToList

Comment: This is a perfect use case for async/await!

Comment: where did you define `userwithIds`?

Comment: @YongQuan - what about `fullControlPermission`, and `contributePermission` and `formData`, and `faqAdminGroup` ?? I don't they are important to the question :p

Comment: @JaromandaX yup, those too

Comment: hi @yongQuan those aren't important info to the chain :) i would just like to refactor my code into a more efficient one. ive worked it out thank you everyone!

Comment: I hope you've gone the async/await

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the simplest version of your code (without the console.log's)

```
this.props.actionHandler.createDivisionList(this.state.divisionQnAListName)
.then(listData => this.props.actionHandler.createListFields(listData.data.Title).then(() => listData))
.then(listData => await this.props.actionHandler.addFieldsToView(listData.data.Title))
.then(() => this.props.actionHandler.createSharePointGroup(this.state.divisionName))
.then(groupInfo => this.props.actionHandler.addUsersToSPGroup(groupInfo.data.Title, userwithIds).then(() => groupInfo))
.then(groupInfo => this.props.actionHandler.breakListPermission(this.state.divisionQnAListName).then(() => groupInfo))
.then(groupInfo => this.props.actionHandler.addGroupToList(this.state.divisionQnAListName, faqAdminGroup[0].Id, fullControlPermission).then(() => groupInfo))
.then(groupInfo => this.props.actionHandler.addGroupToList(this.state.divisionQnAListName, groupInfo.data.Id, contributePermission))
.then(() => this.props.actionHandler.saveMasterItemtoSPList(this.props.masterListName, formData))
.then(res2 => console.log(res2, "after saving!"));
```

With this code, you'll note I've discarded any return values that are never used anyway and chain down required variables (hence why console.log's were removed, because variables like `res` were only ever used in a console.log)

However - this is type of code is a perfect use case for async/await

```
async function someFunction() { // this line exists just to drive home 
                                // the point that this works inside an 
                                // async function only
    const listData =    await this.props.actionHandler.createDivisionList(this.state.divisionQnAListName)
    console.log(listData, "in list creation");
    const res =         await this.props.actionHandler.createListFields(listData.data.Title)
    console.log(res, "after list field creation");
    const r =           await this.props.actionHandler.addFieldsToView(listData.data.Title);
    const groupInfo =   await this.props.actionHandler.createSharePointGroup(this.state.divisionName);
    console.log(groupInfo, "in group creation");
    const afterAdd =    await this.props.actionHandler.addUsersToSPGroup(groupInfo.data.Title,userwithIds);
    const afterBreak =  await this.props.actionHandler.breakListPermission(this.state.divisionQnAListName);
    const admin =       await this.props.actionHandler.addGroupToList(this.state.divisionQnAListName,faqAdminGroup[0].Id,fullControlPermission);
    const last =        await this.props.actionHandler.addGroupToList(this.state.divisionQnAListName,groupInfo.data.Id,contributePermission);
    const res2 =        await this.props.actionHandler.saveMasterItemtoSPList(this.props.masterListName,formData);
    console.log(res2, "after saving!");
```

that is just so flat and sexy, right

Comment: hi , thank you for this i didnt you know you could do this: .then(() => listData)). Thank you!

Comment: never thought I'd see myself write the following statement: use `async`/`await` for such complex chains

Comment: @PageF.P.T - re `.then(() => listData)` - it's just a link in the chain - but really .. do the async/await version (doesn't have to be in an IIFE, I did that when checking the code for syntax errors

Comment: Hi @Jaromanda, what i the difference between the async/ await and the first one?

Comment: well, async/await is "syntax sugar" over promises, that makes writing complex chains with complex dependencies far simpler, as you can see, the code in the async/await version looks almost synchronous - and zero nesting, all those dependencies are just available where they need to be available

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for, but in every case you need to return appropriate data which is required by the next then. Try it, i hope it works fine:

```
this.props.actionHandler.createDivisionList(this.state.divisionQnAListName)
                  .then(listData => {
                      console.log(listData, "in list creation");
                      //createListFields 
                      this.props.actionHandler.createListFields(listData.data.Title);
                    return <some_data>;
                  })
                  .then(res=>{
                      //addFieldsToView (
                    console.log(res, "after list field creation");
                      this.props.actionHandler.addFieldsToView(listData.data.Title);
                    return <some_data>;
                  })
                  .then(r => {
                      this.props.actionHandler.createSharePointGroup(this.state.divisionName)
                    return <some_data>;
                  })
                  .then(groupInfo => {
                    console.log(groupInfo, "in group creation");
                      //add users to group 
                      this.props.actionHandler.addUsersToSPGroup(groupInfo.data.Title,userwithIds)
                    return <some_data>;
                  })
                  .then(afterAdd => {
                      //break list permission
                      this.props.actionHandler.breakListPermission(this.state.divisionQnAListName)
                    return <some_data>;
                  })
                  .then(afterBreak => {
                      //addGroup to list
                      this.props.actionHandler.addGroupToList(this.state.divisionQnAListName,faqAdminGroup[0].Id,fullControlPermission)
                    return <some_data>;
                  })
                  .then(admin => {
                      this.props.actionHandler.addGroupToList(this.state.divisionQnAListName,groupInfo.data.Id,contributePermission)
                    return <some_data>;
                  })
                  .then(last => {
                      this.props.actionHandler.saveMasterItemtoSPList(this.props.masterListName,formData)
                    return <some_data>;
                   })
                  .then(res => {
                      //if success pass success else pass fail to the container
                    console.log(res, "after saving!");
                      //this.props.onSubmission(res);
                  })
                  .catch(err => {
                      //while error 
                });
```

Comment: this code doesn't even come close to parsing as valid javascript

Comment: ofcourse it won't as there are syntax errors because of <some_data>, you need to return the appropriate value there. @JaromandaX

Comment: indeed, but `return <some_data>;.then(last => {` - you'd need a `})` as well, which isn't `<some_data>` ... it's `<some_data>` + `fix up poor syntax`

Comment: you've also broken the promise chain ... completely